# JAXB - Enum annotation allow get value as both int and string causes exceptions

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, mule

I want to be able to get the int value of enum (default) but also the text value, (for example 2 or "TestTwo"). I've tried the code below:

In parent:

```
@XmlElement(name="ProjectType")
private ProjectType projectType;
```

In Enum:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Proj")
@XmlType
@XmlEnum(Integer.class)       //Which class to set here??
public enum ProjectType implements java.io.Serializable {

 @XmlEnumValue("2") TestTwo(2),
 @XmlEnumValue("3") TestThree(3);

 private int projectType = 0;

    private ProjectType(int projectType) {
        this.projectType = projectType;
    }
}
```

But gets exceptions when i run the mule project:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~    [?:1.8.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:3320) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.System$2.getEnumConstantsShared(System.java:1249) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at java.util.EnumMap.getKeyUniverse(EnumMap.java:752) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.demo.ProjectType.values(ProjectType.java:1) ~[?:?]
at com.test.demo.ProjectType.<init>(ProjectType.java:22) ~[?:?]
at com.test.demo.ProjectType.<clinit>(ProjectType.java:13) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:3320) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.System$2.getEnumConstantsShared(System.java:1249) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at java.util.EnumMap.getKeyUniverse(EnumMap.java:752) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
```

I can't see what's wrong here ?

Comment: What's the code that throws the run-time exception?

Comment: Sorry, the exceptions get thrown when I start running the mule Project.

Comment: I don't know what your project is like. You should isolate the problem and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem is the enum that is writed in my post. If i set projectType as an int in parent class it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a parent class like this

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Elem {
    @XmlElement(name="ProjectType")
    private ProjectType projectType;
    //...
}
```

and the enum as posted by you, there's no problem marshalling:

```
<elem>
    <ProjectType>2</ProjectType>
</elem>
```

If I change the enum to

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Proj")
@XmlType
@XmlEnum(String.class)
public enum ProjectType {
  @XmlEnumValue("II")      // or @XmlEnumValue(2)
  TestTwo(2),
  @XmlEnumValue("III")      // or @XmlEnumValue(3)
  TestThree(3);
  // ....
}
```

the output becomes

```
<elem>
  <ProjectType>II</ProjectType>
</elem>
```

I see no particular problem with JAXB. **Edit** Added the Main class.

```
public class Main {
    private static final String XMLIN   = "hello.xml";

    void marshal() throws Exception {
        Elem root = new Elem();
    root.setProjectType( ProjectType.TestTwo );
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( Elem.class );
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.marshal( root, System.out );
    }

    void unmarshal() throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( Elem.class );
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Elem elem = (Elem)u.unmarshal( new File( XMLIN ) );
        System.out.println( "elem projectType " + elem.getProjectType() );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
    main.marshal();
        main.unmarshal();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how's the constructor looks like in the enum class? Do i pass an int? because i still get same errors.

Comment: As I wrote: The enum ProjectType is good as it is. - However: the stack traces run through the init of an EnumMap, and I don't see anything in the snippets you posted related to such a Map. Do you?

Comment: Is it maybe because the input xml is a list of parents, which contains an enum ?

Comment: This shouldn't matter. - You should try to reproduce this with a simple JAXB marshal/unmarshal cycle, bypassing mule and add the code reproducing the problem to your question. I have added the Main program to my answer.

Comment: Hi again, i've tried this and the marshalling works fine, but when it have been unmarshalled the projectType is null.

Comment: Marshalling: <Proj>
        <ProjectType>II</ProjectType>
</Proj>
Unmarshalling: proj projectType null

Comment: There never was "Two" as the `@XmlEnumValue("Two")` for ProjectType TestTwo. If you change the XML data, make sure to change the @Annotations, too.

Comment: There is not Two, I meaned II :)

Comment: Check the spelling of `<ProjectType>...`  and the one of @XmlEnumValue. If you have `ll` in the XML, it will display null, but if you have `II` it will display TestTwo.

Comment: in the xmlfile i have <ProjectType>2<ProjectType> when marshalling get the string value ii to uppercase but when unmashalling i want the string value ii to uppercase when i call .getProjectType on the object but gets null.

Comment: ah, in the annotation you need to have same value as in the parantheses. When I changed it to 2 instead of II it printed TestTwo